# Kind of Taylor expansion for functions of several variables?

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

in my studies of function of several variables I saw the following theorem and I would like to know if it is the equivalent of Taylor's theorem for functions of several variables.

Consider $f:A\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ where all its partial derivatives exists on the open ball $N(X_o, r)$ with $X_0\in A$. Consider $Z$ a vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\lVert Z\rVert\leq r$. Then we have

$f(X_0 + Z) = f(X_0) + \sum_{i}^{n}f_{x_i}^{'}(X_0 + V_i)z_i$ with $V_i=(z_1, ..., z_{i-1}, \theta z_{i}, 0, ..., 0),\quad 0<\theta<1$

To prove this we use induction and the mean value theorem and moreover, under this form, it makes me think of a kind of Taylor Theorem for function of several variables, so I would like to know if it is the case ? Moreover, this theorem does not assume the function to be differentiable but only to have partial derivatives.

My last question is that in my book, it is said that this result is not very used "in practice" but I don't see why since there is not much hypothesis on the function I find.

Thank you a lot !

The book in question is "Cours de mathématiques pour économistes" from Philippe Michel.

Comment: I agree, this looks like a first order Taylor series expansion for the case of $n$ variables. However, it is somewhat different because the derivatives are not evaluated in $X_{0}$, but shifted towards the endpoint. This is a bit peculiar. But since the formula is first order, this is probably allowed. Not sure why this formula is "better" than the usual first order Taylor series.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! ,

Comment: @coboy Could you cite the book please?

Comment: @PavelKocourek Of course ! This is  "Cours de mathématiques pour économistes" from Philippe Michel, unfortunately the book is in french and it was published in 1984

Comment: You can compare the theorem you mention to the Taylor's theorem, for example in there notes https://www.math.toronto.edu/courses/mat237y1/20199/notes/Chapter2/S2.6.html#sect-2.6.2 that I googled.  Think of a function that has partial derivatives everywhere, but does not have (total) derivative at $X_0$ and you should see the difference. In my view this theorem is not so useful because you need to consider derivatives at different points than at $X_0$, I rather like to be able to approximate the function locally based on the derivative at a single point.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer me! In fact you are totally right. I took the time to think about this theorem and clearly we consider only a function that has partial derivatives in this theorem and also it is not very interesting in practice, it is much better to do as you say and work at the point $X_0$ !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of this as the Taylor's theorem for multivariable functions with Lagrange remainder, where the polynomial that is used to approximate the function (the Taylor polynomial) is of degree $0$ or less (the polynomial is $f(X_0)$). But for the Lagrange remainder to work in general, partial derivatives in the remainder part must be continous (for it to work for higher orders). So thinking of this as a generalized mean value theorem is better. For more information you can check: [https://sites.math.washington.edu/~folland/Math425/taylor2.pdf](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Efolland/Math425/taylor2.pdf)